# How to remove a group of lines from a file?

Tags: text-processing, logs, ksh

I'm writing a ksh script to parse a log file and send an email when
important messages are found.  Some messages are informational and
I'd like to ignore them.

The log file has format

```
2018-01-24.08.24.35.875675    some text

    more text
    more text
    more text
    more text

2018-01-24.08.24.37.164538    some text

    more text
    more text
    INF9999W        <-- informational text
    more text

2018-01-24.08.24.46.8602545    some text

    more text
    more text
    more text
```

The timestamp would be considered the message separator, with the
timestamp belonging to the message that follows it.  I'd like to 
search the file for each occurrences of "information text" and then
remove that whole message from the file (from preceding timestamp 
until just before the next timestamp).

How can I easily determine the line numbers of the preceding and
following timestamps so I remove those lines with:

```
awk 'NR<'$preceding_ts' || NR >='$following_ts'
```

My way is to get all the timestamp lines into a file and then loop
through that file until I find the timestamp lines that are just
before and after the 'information-text' line #.  It seems like a 
lot of work, particularly on a large file.  Is there a more efficient 
way.

```
integer inf_line
integer last_ts_line
integer cur_ts
cp $error_log $copy_log
while true
do
   inf_line=$(grep -n "INF99999W" $copy_log | head -1 | cut -f1 -d":")
   if [[ $inf_line -eq 0 ]]
   then
      break
   fi     
   grep -n -E "^20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-" $copy_log | cut -f1 -d":" > $ts_lines
   last_ts_line=99999999
   cat $ts_lines | while read cur_ts
   do       
      if [[ $cur_ts -gt $inf_line && $last_ts_line -lt $inf_line ]]
      then
         awk 'NR<'$last_ts_line' || NR >='$cur_ts'' $copy_log > $temp_log
         cp $temp_log $copy_log
         last_ts_line=$cur_ts
         break
      fi
      last_ts_line=$cur_ts
   done
   if [[ $last_ts_line -lt $inf_line ]]
   then
      awk 'NR<'$last_ts_line'' $copy_log > $temp_log
      cp $temp_log $copy_log
   fi
done
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach it by storing the lines of the current message, and when the message ends, printing the stored lot if there was no `INF` marker seen. Here, `d` holds the lines of the current message (d for data), `p` tells if we want to print the stored lines or not.

```
awk -vinfo='INF99+' \
    '/^20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]/ {
         if (p) printf "%s", d; d = $0 ORS; p=1; next } 
     $0 ~ info {p=0} 
     {d = d $0 ORS} 
     END {if (p) printf "%s", d}' < log
```

The first rule here matches on the timestamp lines, prints any stored lines if `p` is true, stores this line and sets `p` to one.
The second rules resets `p` to zero if a line with the `info` pattern is seen; the pattern is set to the variable with `-vinfo=...`.
The third rule appends the current line to those collected, and the `END` rule again just prints the collected lines if `p` is set.

---

We could also write it like this, this would check the `info` pattern also on the timestamp line:

```
awk -vinfo='INF99+' \
    '/^20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]/ {
         if (p) { printf "%s", d }; d = ""; p=1; } 
     $0 ~ info {p=0} 
     {d = d $0 ORS} 
     END {if (p) printf "%s", d}' < log
```

---

In general, it's probably a good idea to write stuff like this in `awk` or Perl. The result will at least be much faster to run than a shell script that forks dozens of copies of `grep`, `awk`, and `cut` etc...

Comment: Wow.  I need to brush up on my awk skills.  I've typically used it for simple operations.  Your code works as advertised.   I'll be using a file to supply a list of "INF99" type values.  How do I use a variable in your expression to pass in those values?  Replacing your INF99 with $string didn't do it (again, my sub-par awk skills). Thanks.

Comment: @Scavenger, it's easier to pass stuff like that as variables to awk with `-vvar=value` (or `-vvar="$shellvar"`), see edit. The script is in single quotes, so the shell will not expand variables inside it, and if you change it to double quotes, then you'll need to escape all the other `$` signs inside it.

Comment: Just trying to wrap my head around this.  Would it make sense to change {p=0} to {p=0; next} to avoid adding to d since it will be discarded anyway?

Comment: @Scavenger, you could do that, or you could put `p` as a condition for adding to `d` ( `p {d = d $0 ORS}` ), but I doubt it makes much difference (and in any case, the script might collect any number of lines before seeing that the current block should be dropped.)

Comment: If there's a chance that the timestamp line could also have the text to exclude (not in my initial example), would I just remove the 'next' after p=1 so the line gets excluded by the "$0~ info {p=0}" line?  Why does the 2nd rule not need braces around it like the 3rd rule does?
  Thanks again. Fascinating stuff.

Comment: @Scavenger, hmm, yes, though then you need to set `d = ""` on the timestamp block, since two lines below, the current line is added regardless.(and we don't want to add the timestamp line twice). I'm not exactly sure which rule you mean. The code blocks have braces around them, they always do in `awk`. But the `{d = d $0 ORS}` block doesn't have a condition on it, unlike the others, so it runs on every line.

Comment: (And now SE starts complaining about extended discussions in comments, so I'll leave you to playing with it. I would link some useful awk guide / 
 other resource here, but I'm not sure what would be a good one, sorry.)